# Why jQuery each() loop is getting all the elements of all iteration in each iteration?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

Why this script is not getting the H3 inside each iteration, but all the H3 of the all iterations each time?!

JS:

```
            $('a.grid-box').each(function(index){
                $( '.meta-info h3');
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
      <a class="grid-box" href="">
        <div class="links-icons meta-info">
          <h3>Title 1</h3>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="grid-box" href="">
        <div class="links-icons meta-info">
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
etc...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your selector is making no reference to the `a.grid-box` iteration context, and so is searching globally.

Change

```
$('a.grid-box').each(function(index){
  $('.meta-info h3');
});
```

to

```
$('a.grid-box').each(function(index){
  $(this).find('.meta-info h3');
});
```

```js
$('a.grid-box').each(function(index) {
  var h3 = $(this).find('.meta-info h3');
  console.log(h3.length, h3.text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <a class="grid-box" href="">
    <div class="links-icons meta-info">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="grid-box" href="">
    <div class="links-icons meta-info">
      <h3>Title 2</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  etc...
</div>
```

Also note the `;.` typo in your original code.

Comment: I already had that ```$(this).find()``` and it did the same. The context .grid-box it only has one H3, but I'm getting each time all the H3 contained in each .grid-box

Comment: @Dedalos01 then you'll need to add a [mcve] to your question to demonstrate the problem as this code does what it says: finds a single h3 inside each `a.grid-box`: https://jsfiddle.net/op3w7ehm/1/

Comment: Thanks I have fixed the typo.

Comment: My real context it's a little bit more complex I find out what was going on. Thank you!